# My simple code doesn't give an output

Tags: c, output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int year;
    float principal, amount, inrate, period, value;
    printf ("Please enter principal");
    scanf ("%f", principal);
    amount = principal;
    printf ("Please enter interest rate");
    scanf ("%f", inrate);
    year = 0;
    printf ("Please enter period");
    scanf ("%f", period);
        while(year <=  period)
            {printf ("%d %f\n", year, amount);
            value = amount + amount*inrate;
            year = year + 1;
            amount = value;
            }
        getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried running this code but I have no output at all. There are 0 warnings and messages. Frankly, I don't know if the code will serve the intended purpose without being able to run it! Please help.

Comment: Remember to use `&` with `scanf`.

Comment: Do compile with `-Wall` option.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code one line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you are having are twofold. The first, `scanf` requires a pointer to store values. (e.g. `scanf ("%f", principal);` should be `scanf ("%f", &principal);`)

Another issue to be aware of is reading values with `scanf` will leave a newline `'\n'` in the input buffer `stdin` each time you press `[Enter]`. `scanf` will read the number you enter, but leave the newline in `stdin`. The next time you call `scanf` it sees the newline (value: `0xa` hex, `10`) in `stdin` and reads that as the next value.

**Note:** in this case, `%f` will skip the newline, so it is not necessary. However, be aware that decimals or strings read by `scanf` will be effected. Always keep this in mind when using `scanf`.

If faced with `scanf` seeming to skip over expected input, a simple solution is the flush (empty) the input buffer. (an example of how to handle this is provided in function `flush_stdin` below). Simply call `flush_stdin` after each call to `scanf` where this is a potential problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// #include <conio.h>

void flush_stdin ()
{
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main(void)
{
    int year = 0;   /* Always INITIALIZE your variables */
    float principal, amount, inrate, period, value;
    principal = amount = inrate = period = value = 0;

    printf ("Please enter principal: ");
    scanf ("%f", &principal);

    amount = principal;

    printf ("Please enter interest rate: ");
    scanf ("%f", &inrate);

    year = 0;

    printf ("Please enter period: ");
    scanf ("%f", &period);

    while(year <=  period)
    {
        printf ("%3d %10.2f\n", year, amount);
        value = amount + amount*inrate;
        year = year + 1;
        amount = value;
    }

    // getch();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_noop
Please enter principal: 123.45
Please enter interest rate: .05
Please enter period: 24
  0     123.45
  1     129.62
  2     136.10
  3     142.91
  4     150.05
  5     157.56
  6     165.43
  7     173.71
  8     182.39
  9     191.51
 10     201.09
 11     211.14
 12     221.70
 13     232.78
 14     244.42
 15     256.64
 16     269.48
 17     282.95
 18     297.10
 19     311.95
 20     327.55
 21     343.93
 22     361.12
 23     379.18
 24     398.14
```

Comment: The `%f` format skips white space such as newlines, blanks and tabs without any problem.  The `flush_stdin()` call is overkill here, especially since you aren't checking whether the input worked or not.  It would make sense as part of an error handling strategy.

Comment: Granted. It's the intermixing string and numbers in successive calls that kills you. But when providing examples to help newcomers, overkill isn't all bad. I'll drop a note. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried running this code but I have no output at all

Really? I got 6 warnings and a segfault! what compiler are you using?

```
        ||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
        main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
        main.cpp|8|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float*', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat]|
        main.cpp|11|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float*', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat]|
        main.cpp|14|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float*', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat]|
        main.cpp|8|warning: 'principal' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
        main.cpp|11|warning: 'inrate' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
        main.cpp|14|warning: 'period' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
        ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 6 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

The code looks like some sort of interest calculator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest)

try that code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        int year;
        float principal, amount, inrate, period, value;
        printf ("Please enter principal ");
        scanf ("%f", &principal);
        amount = principal;
        printf ("Please enter interest rate ");
        scanf ("%f", &inrate);
        year = 0;
        printf ("Please enter period ");
        scanf ("%f", &period);
            while(year <=  period)
                {
                printf ("%d %f\n", year, amount);
                value = amount + amount*inrate;
                year = year + 1;
                amount = value;
                }
            getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

scanf reads data from stdin and stores them according to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments. So if you want to save something in the variable with scanf, you should give pointer as argument with &.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the `&` address-of before the variable arguments in the `scanf()` calls, it works. But I didn't check the arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int year;
    float principal, amount, inrate, period, value;
    printf ("Please enter principal ");
    scanf ("%f", &principal);                   // <-- added &
    amount = principal;
    printf ("Please enter interest rate ");
    scanf ("%f", &inrate);                      // <-- added &
    year = 0;
    printf ("Please enter period ");
    scanf ("%f", &period);                      // <-- added &
    while(year <=  period) {
        printf ("%d %f\n", year, amount);
        value = amount + amount*inrate;
        year = year + 1;
        amount = value;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
```

}